# Using button and objects in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.tabs()

    def home(self):
        df = QtGui.QPushButton('hello', self)
        df.move(300, 300)
        self.show()

    def tabs(self):
        btn_1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Home', self)
        btn_1.clicked.connect(self.home)
        self.show()
```

Trying to access the module 'home()' and print button 'hello' when button btn_1 in module tabs is clicked. Not happening..

Comment: Hey Rajesh! What is happening instead? Is there an error message? What do you think is going wrong? Providing more information makes it easier to help. :)

Comment: sorry i was not clear. The btn_1 button is showing but when i click it the df button from home() module is not displayed the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the new object it appears hidden, so that it is visible uses the `show()` function.

```
def home(self):
    df = QtGui.QPushButton('hello', self)
    df.move(300, 300)
    df.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked right away.
I was using self.show() insted of df.show()..